# What kind of launch escape system (LES) does Dream Chaser have?

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight, launch-escape-system

What kind of launch escape system will be aboard Dream Chaser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [Dream Chaser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream_Chaser_%28spacecraft%29) is based on the [HL-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HL-20_Personnel_Launch_System) lifting body design, I presume it would have same or similar Launch Escape System (LES). What follows are to the question the most relevant excerpts from the [Launch Pad Abort of the HL-20 Lifting Body](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/24298984_Launch-pad_abort_capabilities_of_the_HL-20_lifting_body) journal article (including diagrams).

---

JOURNAL OF GUIDANCE, CONTROL, AND DYNAMICS
Vol. 17, No. 6, November-December 1994

**[Launch Pad Abort of the HL-20 Lifting Body](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/24298984_Launch-pad_abort_capabilities_of_the_HL-20_lifting_body)**:

> The capability of the HL-20 lifting-body spacecraft to perform an
>   abort maneuver from the launch pad to a horizontal landing was
>   studied. This study involved both piloted and batch simulation models
>   of the vehicle. A point-mass model of the vehicle was used for
>   trajectory optimization studies. The piloted simulation was performed
>   in a fixed-base simulator. A candidate maneuver was developed and
>   refined for the worst-case launch-pad-to- landing-site geometry using
>   an iterative procedure of off-line maneuver analysis followed by
>   piloted evaluations and heuristic improvements to the candidate
>   maneuver. The resulting maneuver demonstrates the launch site abort
>   capability of the HL-20 and dictates requirements for nominal abort
>   motor performance. The sensitivity of the maneuver to variations in
>   several design parameters was documented. Introduction T 20,000-lb
>   lifting body with a maximum subsonic lift-to-drag ratio of 4.3 (see
>   Fig. 1) capable of being launched vertically into low Earth orbit with
>   a crew of two and up to eight passengers using an expendable launch
>   vehicle and of being landed horizontally following re-entry. Both
>   manual and automatic landing capabilities are planned.

[image: Figure 1]

> A 6700-1b adapter module will be used to connect the HL-20 to the
>   launch vehicle. (See fig. 2.) This adapter design will include a
>   launch escape system that is intended to thrust the HL-20 away from
>   the booster in case of a malfunction either during the actual launch
>   or on the pad prior to launch (on-pad abort). Acceleration levels on
>   tile order of 8g's (lg = 32.2 ft/sec 2) would be required to propel
>   the vehicle a safe distance away from a malfunctioning booster. After
>   a specified time, the abort-motor thrust would drop to approximately
>   lg for an additional specified amount of time to avoid excessive
>   velocities and associated drag. The adapter module would be jettisoned
>   following abort-motor burnout.

[image: Figure 2]

> The capabilities of the HL-20 to successfully abort during the ascent
>   phase of a launch have been treated in a separate study by Naftel and
>   Taley; the on-pad-abort maneuver, performed in an emergency prior to
>   ignition, is the subject of this paper. Since the initial lift-to-drag
>   ratio precluded a glide to a nearby runway, original launch pad abort
>   scenarios were similar to those used for earlier manned capsules,
>   i.e., an abort to an ocean landing using a recovery parachute.
>   Additional aerodynamic refinements of the HL-20 configuration led to
>   increased subsonic lift-to-drag ratios and a higher performance launch
>   escape system abort motor was specified.

Full text is available in the journal article: [Launch-pad abort capabilities of the HL-20 lifting body](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/24298984_Launch-pad_abort_capabilities_of_the_HL-20_lifting_body)

Answer (score 8):

While Dream Chaser is, indeed, based on HL-20, one of the few significant changes was removing the launch abort adapter and replacing it with an [integrated abort system](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2014/07/08/sierra-nevada-completes-dream-chaser-propulsion-reaction-control-milestone/). This was made possible by using a pair of liquid bipropellant engines (though originally [the plan was to use hybrid motors](http://www.parabolicarc.com/2014/08/19/snc-abandons-hybrid-motors-dream-chaser/)) as the spacecraft's main propulsion system. The same engines could therefore be used for both orbital adjustments and aborts.